# how to create disk label without creation filesystem on new disk

Tags: rhel, filesystems, disk, mkfs, lsblk

we have rhel 7.2 server , server is VM server

and we add new disk - `sde`

with the following example we create ext file system with label - `disk2`

```
mkfs.ext4 -L disk2 /dev/sde
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sde is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Discarding device blocks: done
Filesystem label=disk2
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
262144 inodes, 1048576 blocks
52428 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=1073741824
32 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

so we get

```
lsblk -o +FSTYPE,LABEL | grep sde
sde                8:64   0     4G  0 disk                       ext4        disk2
```

is it possible to create on new disk only the label **but without creation of file system**?

example of expected output ( without file system on disk )

```
lsblk -o +FSTYPE,LABEL | grep sde
sde                8:64   0     4G  0 disk                         disk2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels shown by `lsblk` (or rather, `blkid`) in its `LABEL` column are the file system labels, which are only available on file systems capable of storing a label. A block device with no file system can’t have such a label.

GPT partitions can also be labeled, and `lsblk` shows that with `PARTLABEL`. But that’s not an option for whole disks either.

Comment: maybe other solution , I will explain my self , lets say we have a new 3 disks , and I want to join one of  this disk to VG by some bash script that will do it auto , but script will choose the disk by some identification like label or something similar  , so can we do something about this?

Comment: ok then I will post new question

Comment: I post new question per you request - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631027/linux-is-it-possible-to-identify-specific-new-disk-in-order-to-join-the-new-di

Comment: regarding my new post do you think its possible ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [What does disk label mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503254/338177)

> - There's the label inside partitions (**more correctly inside filesystems**) just called LABEL by `lsblk -f` [On all disks but not for
>   special partitions like swap, procfs, sysfs]
> - There's the label outside partitions but in the partition table called PARTLABEL by `lsblk -f` [Only gpt disks have this capacity]
> - There's the label outermost which as you rightly suspect is more usually called 'partition table'. This last terminology is more used
>   in other Unix cultures eg OpenBSD, Oracle and BSD.

Answer (score 0):

On Rhel7 (assuming the backend supports a label)

e2label /dev/sde               (display current label)
e2label /dev/sde NEWLABEL      (Change to or add  NEWLABEL)