# linux + is it possible to identify specific new disk in order to join the new disk to VG

Tags: linux, disk, fdisk, lsblk

we want to build new bash script that will join one of the new disks to volume group ( VG )

lets say we have linux machine and we add `10` new disks

the target is to do manual "label" on one of the disks and then by running the bash script  , it will select the "label" disk by `lsblk` or similar command , and will join this disk to `VG`

Comment: Have a look at the `/dev/disk/by-*` symlinks.

Comment: this isnt help , we need to "label" the disk so we can identify the disk by cli , and then run the script and script will select the "label" disk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to "label" a disk without actually formatting it something because you need to write the label somewhere, which usually means a filesystem header. You can [add tags to PVs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lvm_tags) but this requires create LVM PV format first on the disk. If you need to identify a specific drive, you need to use information this drive provides so this usually means either [WWN/WWID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Name) or serial number. `lsblk` can print both of these:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT SERIAL          WWN
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk            S3Z9NB0KB83128X 0x5002538e40aa0206
```

and these are also used to create symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-id`

Answer (score 2):

## An alternative idea

You could keep a database (key, value pair) of disk IDs and names. You would store it else where. You can't store it on the disks, as the disks arrive empty, and will later be written to (ever-writing your label). You would have to chose an ID type that is baked into the device (does not change if un-plugged, is never re-used).

I don't know if there are existing tools, or if you would have to make them.